# Android: Use setContentView() after Thread finished

Tags: java, android, multithreading, oncreate, setcontentview

I want to use the setContentView() method after a thread has completed his task. 
But how could I realize this, as its not possible to use this method inside the thread? 
When using this method in the onCreate() method while the thread is running, I also don´t get the correct result, cause the layout wich should be displayed with the first "setContentView(R.layout.load_screen)" is not displayed.

My onCreate() Method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Open loading screen
    setContentView(R.layout.load_screen);
    this.loadingScreen();  // In this method the new Thread will start.
}
```

My loadingScreen() Method: (After the thread completed I would like to use setContentView() again)

```
 public void loadingScreen(){
    // prepare for a progress bar dialog
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    //reset progress bar status
    progressBarStatus = 0;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
        while (progressBarStatus < 100) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   
          // process some tasks
          progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

          // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
          try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          // Update the progress bar
          progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
            }
          });
        }

        // ok, file is downloaded,
        if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

            // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
      }
       }).start();
 }
```

Comment: send a broadcast or use a callback interface !!

Comment: Why do you want to call setContentView()? It should only be called once per Activity. If you need a new screen, consider starting a new Activity.

Comment: or u can use AsyncTask and call your setContentView method in onPostExecute() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Handler to update the ui inside the thread. or u can simply use runOnUiThread to update the ui. and u dont want to use setcontentview method to change the ui, u can simply use layout inflater to fetch another layout to ur viewgroup.